# c# compare 2 list of tuples

Tags: c#, list, tuples

I have 2 list `List<(string, string, string)>`  I would like to print out a comparison of the 2 lists by the first tuple element e.g. ("123","4","1") and ("123","a","b") from list 1 and list 2 are equivalent.

Is there a simple way to print out a comparison similiar to a SQL full join?  If element exist both list get the 2 tuples otherwise specify that it is unique to 1 list.

```
("123","4","1")  and ("123","a","b")
("23","4","1")   and ("23","a","b")
NULL             and ("423","a","b")
("77","4","1")   and  NULL
```

Comment: Can you put the  data that we could test pls? I don think that you have "and" inside of it. And if they are in the same order ? And as it always acked here pls show us the code you have done  so far, or you are expecting anybodt else to work for you?

Comment: and is not needed just to separate the 2 data and what do you mean same order the 2 lists?  I can attempt to sort beforehand yes.

Comment: What if we  have ("123","4","1") ,  ("123","5","1")  and just  ("123","a","b")  what couples shoud we select?

Comment: i dont know throw exception maybe that should not happen.

Comment: This is why wee need a real data to help you.